# How to evaluate the effect of different methods of handling missing values?

Tags: python, missing-data, imputation

I am a total beginner and I am trying to compare different methods of handling missing data. In order to evaluate the effect of each method (drop raws with missing values, drop columns with missigness over 40%, impute with the mean, impute with the KNN), I compare the results of the LDA accuracy and LogReg accuracy on the training set between a dataset with 10% missing values, 20% missing values against the results of the original complete dataset. Unfortunately, I get pretty much the same results even between the complete dataset and the dataset with 20% missing-ness. I don't know what I am doing wrong.

```
from numpy import nan
    from numpy import isnan

    from pandas import read_csv
    from sklearn.impute import SimpleImputer

    from sklearn.discriminant_analysis import LinearDiscriminantAnalysis
    from sklearn.model_selection import KFold
    from sklearn.model_selection import cross_val_score


    #dataset = read_csv('telecom_churn_rev10.csv')
    dataset = read_csv('telecom_churn_rev20.csv')
    dataset = dataset.replace(nan, 0)

    values = dataset.values
    X = values[:,1:11]
    y = values[:,0]


    dataset.fillna(dataset.mean(), inplace=True)
    #dataset.fillna(dataset.mode(), inplace=True)
    print(dataset.isnull().sum())
    imputer = SimpleImputer(missing_values = nan, strategy = 'mean')
    transformed_values = imputer.fit_transform(X)
    print('Missing: %d' % isnan(transformed_values).sum())


    model = LinearDiscriminantAnalysis()

    cv = KFold(n_splits = 3, shuffle = True, random_state = 1)
    result = cross_val_score(model, X, y, cv = cv, scoring = 'accuracy')
    print('Accuracy: %.3f' % result.mean())
    #print('Accuracy: %.3f' % result.mode())

    print(dataset.describe())
    print(dataset.head(20))

    from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split
    X_train, X_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(X, y, test_size = 0.2, random_state = 0)

    from sklearn.preprocessing import StandardScaler
    sc = StandardScaler()
    X_train = sc.fit_transform(X_train)
    X_test = sc.transform(X_test)

    from sklearn.linear_model import LogisticRegression
    classifier = LogisticRegression(random_state = 0)
    classifier.fit(X_train, y_train)

    y_pred = classifier.predict(X_test)

    from sklearn.metrics import confusion_matrix, accuracy_score
    cm = confusion_matrix(y_test, y_pred)
    print(cm)
    accuracy_score(y_test,y_pred)

    from sklearn import metrics
    # make predictions on X
    expected = y
    predicted = classifier.predict(X)
    # summarize the fit of the model
    print(metrics.classification_report(expected, predicted))
    print(metrics.confusion_matrix(expected, predicted))

    # make predictions on X test
    expected = y_test
    predicted = classifier.predict(X_test)
    # summarize the fit of the model
    print(metrics.confusion_matrix(expected, predicted))
    print(metrics.classification_report(expected, predicted))
```

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

You replace all your missing values with 0 at that line : `dataset = dataset.replace(nan, 0)`. After this line, you have a full dataset without missing values. So, the `.fillna()` and the `SimpleImputer()` are useless after that line.

Comment: Thank you so much for your response! The thing is that I get this error: "Input contains NaN, infinity or a value too large for dtype('float64')" when I don't do the transformation from nan to 0. I feel like unless I convert to 0, the mean cannot be calculated and therefore imputed. Is there a way to replace the zeros in given columns with the respective mean of each of these columns? Thanks in advance for your time!!

Comment: At which line do you have this error ? I think this is at that line : `result = cross_val_score(model, X, y, cv = cv, scoring = 'accuracy')`  You need to use `transformed_values` instead of X

Comment: Thank you! After getting rid of "dataset = dataset.replace(nan, 0" and  substituting X both here: result = cross_val_score(model, X, y, cv = cv, scoring = 'accuracy') and here: predicted = classifier.predict(X) with transformed_values, the error was resolved but the results are still pretty much identical with the original complete dataset. LDA accuracy (original dataset) - 0.850, LDA accuracy (the same dataset with 20% missing values which were imputed with the mean) - 0.848. LogReg (original) - 0.87, LogReg (imputed) - 0.87. Is this normal?

Comment: It depends on your data (how and why your data are missing). An imputation will not always improve significatively your accuracy